# Multi-page URL Fallback (index.html & subpage.html)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to deploy a multi-page Vue.js app using google apps python engine.

In order for the Vue.js application to work I need all URL's to fallback so the vue javascript router can take over.

**Index.html links**:

> /foo
>
> /bar
>
> /foo/bar

**Subpage.html links**:

> /subpage/foo
>
> /subpage/bar
>
> /subpage/foo/bar

In my current configuration if I remove the wildcard from the index, then the subpage is accessible, but the index links no longer work. Is it possible to achieve multiple fallbacks, first to '/' and second to '/subpage/'?

I've included my app.yaml which, in my opinion should work as written but doesn't.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
  # Fonts and images
  - url: /(.+\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp))
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.+\.(eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp))
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

  # CSS, Javascript, text and other file types
  - url: /(.+\.(css|js|xml|txt|map))
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.+\.(css|js|xml|txt|map))
    expiration: "10m"
    secure: always

  # HTML pages
  - url: /(.+\.html)
    static_files: dist/\1
    upload: dist/(.+\.html)
    expiration: '10m'
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      X-UA-Compatible: 'IE=edge'

  # Index entry point
  - url: /.*
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html
    expiration: '10m'
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      X-UA-Compatible: 'IE=edge'

  # Subpage entry point
  - url: /subpage/.*
    static_files: dist/subpage.html
    upload: dist/subpage.html
    expiration: '10m'
    secure: always
    http_headers:
      X-UA-Compatible: 'IE=edge'
  

skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
  - ^(.*/)?app\.yml
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#
  - ^(.*/)?.*~
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
  - ^(.*/)?\..*
  - ^(.*/)?tests$
  - ^(.*/)?test$
  - ^test/(.*/)?
  - ^COPYING.LESSER
  - ^README\..*
  - \.gitignore
  - ^\.git/.*
  - \.*\.lint$
  - ^node_modules/(.*/)?
  - public/*
  - src/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `- url: /.*` catches EVERYTHING not yet caught.  So, the handlers never get to `/subpage/.*`

Move the `/subpage/.*` handler above the wildcard `- url: /.*`:

```
# Subpage entry point
- url: /subpage/.*
  static_files: dist/subpage.html
  upload: dist/subpage.html
  expiration: '10m'
  secure: always
  http_headers:
    X-UA-Compatible: 'IE=edge'

# Index entry point
- url: /.*
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  expiration: '10m'
  secure: always
  http_headers:
    X-UA-Compatible: 'IE=edge'
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a major headache.